# Will 1h 20 mins be enough to transit via Munich with immigration (type C Schengen)?

Tags: transit, schengen-visas, short-connections, muc

I am an Indian citizen with Canadian permanent residency and I will be traveling via the Mumbai-Munich-Frankfurt-Toronto route (all flights under a single ticket - Lufthansa) soon. From what I gather, I would need the type C (short stay) Schengen visa for this trip since I have a Schengen domestic leg on my trip and will have to undergo immigration at Munich airport.

It'll be very helpful to know if 1 hour 20 mins will be enough to transit via Munich airport when my inbound flight (Mumbai-Munich) and the next outbound flight (Munich-Frankfurt) will be operating from the same terminal (Terminal 2). 
Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note: I've never flown through Terminal 2, but I would say at Terminal 1 it is not enough unless you're willing to cut the line stating that you have a connection to catch. Flying in from a country with a visa requirement, I've had to wait 45m in immigration line before, and 10-20m on security. When doing self transfers, do note that baggage can take anywhere from 20 minutes to over an hour to arrive upon plane landing (latter mostly relevant for strike days).

Answer (score 9):

Since the airline has sold this connection to you as a single ticket, the airline clearly thinks it is sufficient.

In my experience, Munich is a very efficient airport, so you'll be fine as long as the incoming flight is on time.  And if you do miss the connecting flight because the flight from BOM is delayed, Lufthansa will put you on the next available flight for free.  Flights between MUC and FRA are very frequent.

Comment: Going MUC-FRA might be easy, but the FRA-YYZ flights may be less frequent if there are issues. Still, +1. Which I now see that [Hilmar has addressed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/183539/42899).

Answer (score 7):

That should be fine.

It looks you are arriving at 5:35am and then are probably booked on the 8:00am MUC->FRA flight. If you miss this, there are other flights at 9:00am, 10:00am etc. All of this arrive an hour later.

I assume you are on the 13:55 flight from FRA to Toronto, so there is plenty of time in FRA to make your connection. Even if that goes sideways, there is a codeshare with Air Canada at 17:05.